# Prevent music players from auto play on bluetooth connect

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, music-player, bluetooth-audio

Whenever I connect my android device with a bluetooth device, it automatically starts spotify and starts playing.
As far as I know this also happens to other users/players (according to google)

How can I prevent this (without signing out of spotify)?

Android: 6.0.1
Spotify Version: 6.2.0.1015

Comment: @beeshyams yes it is, but the solution should also cover unrooted devices, as this is not only a concern to me.

Comment: @beeshyams How would a tasker solution look like? You can add it as an answer here for rooted devices and if someone would come up with a non-root solution, he could edit your answer.

Comment: It's not mine. I don't know Tasker so will not post that solution. But [here it is]( https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-disable-bluetooth-automatic-playback-on-any-android-phone/)

Comment: My solution is using [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) which is another automation app. You can test it and let me know if it works- I can't test since I don't use Spotify. Trigger: Bluetooth Event > device connected > any device Action: Kill app > Spotify (requires root ). You can test this in 5 minutes

Comment: @beeshyams I like the link you posted! AFAICT it doesnt need root (since you can do adb commands via usb debugging) only need to enable Tasker accessibility service, good research though!

Comment: @beeshyams unfortunately I don't have Spotify installed too, perhaps I could have tried it but at the moment I can't replicate the autoplay with my music apps :( thanks though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62084/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-xavier-fakerat).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Background**

Major part of this guide was extracted here: [How to Disable Bluetooth Automatic Playback on any Android Phone](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-disable-bluetooth-automatic-playback-on-any-android-phone/)

The point of this guide **isn't to disable Bluetooth music entirely,** otherwise the latter can easily be achieved by:

Disable Bluetooth Music : Settings >> Bluetooth >> Your device(Car) >> Settings  then uncheck audio support.

..and this simply destroys the whole purpose of the guide.

It is important to know that *autoplay* is a *feature* of many Bluetooth devices, despite the fact people do see this "feature" as a problem though, which is the original reason the original author wrote the guide.

---

**Understanding Bluetooth Autoplay on Android**

- What essentially happens when you connect a Bluetooth device that sends an autoplay command is that this command is seen as a KeyEvent for toggle play/pause in Android.
- Applications with a MediaButtonReceiver broadcast receiver can then react to this Media Button event.
- Android keeps track of the last application that requests to receive Media Button events.

> Any new media application can take over to listen to Media Button key
>   events by calling `setMediaButtonReceiver` in AudioManager, and that
>   application will handle Media Button key events until another
>   application requests control.

You can actually see which application is currently set to respond to these key events by entering the following ADB command:

`adb shell settings get secure media_button_receiver`

On the author’s device, this command yielded the following output:

`com.google.android.music/com.google.android.music.playback.MediaButtonIntentReceiver`

> This is the broadcast receiver set up by Google Play Music to respond
>   to Media Button key events. So if I plug in my Bluetooth device, my
>   phone will automatically start playback in Google Play Music.

**Disabling Bluetooth Autoplay with Tasker**

**Profile (or Trigger)**

- Goto Profiles Tab and click the "+"
- Event >> State >> Net >> BT Connected
- Tap back to exit from this window

**Task**

You will notice as soon as you exit, you will be prompted to link this to a Task

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select "New Task + "
- You can just keep it anonymous or give it a name
- Click "+" to add new Action
- Media >> Media Button Events >> Grab
- Tap back to exit from this task

*AFAIK root is not necessary for this task*

[image] [image] [image]

Once you’re done, Tasker should now automatically set itself as the Media Button Receiver in Android upon connection to your selected Bluetooth devices. This way, the play/pause action that is sent will not be received by any of your media applications, but instead by Tasker

Unfortunately I couldn’t get Spotify or Soundcloud music application to replicate the issue. **However, I retested this feature using a PC with the remote audio service (Bluetooth module on my PC supports that) to test the bluetooth autoplay feature.**

**Tests done**

1. Enabled Bluetooth audio service (to use PC speakers to listen to remote audio).
2. Open two different music apps on android and played music and play
3. Created a “media button grab” in Tasker to handle Media Button key events.
4. Retested (2) with Tasker running the previously created task.

[image]

**Results**

1. On test (2) the audio output was transferred to PC speakers indicating that the autoplay feature was still active.
2. After performing test (4), **the audio sound output came from android and was not transferred to PC speakers. Which essentially solves the issue.**

---

Alternatively..

Head to playstore and get [Bluetooth connect & Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player)

[image] [image] [image]

You can tell it which app should play for each bluetooth device (or to NOT play on a given BT device)

**Acknowledgements**

- Original author: [Mishaal Rahman](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-disable-bluetooth-automatic-playback-on-any-android-phone/)
- [Beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams)

Comment: Install a paying app...right... is there an actual solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Bixby routines is you have a Samsung.  It might be set to turn on music as soon as Bluetooth is connected.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Bluetooth playback, create a Tasker profile and associated task. For the task, choose "Music Play." I have mine set to play a 1 second clip of silence such as [this](https://archive.org/details/1secondofsilence_201911). This grabs the playback and does not automatically continue to the prior app playing media.

I tested this on Android 13 (LineageOS 20) with a Pixel 4a.

I tried the solution suggesting to grab playback with Tasker or the `media_button_receiver` option (both rooted and not), but neither worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you are been annoyed by your smart android phone auto starting the music when you start your car. Here is the solution I found snooping around:
Open up your Google Chrome browser on he phone, click on the right upper corner bottom, click on settings, advance, site settings, media and turn off auto play. Bingo.
Now you can play any media when you want.
JT.